# Searching for data based on a checkBox on a ASP.NET site

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a problem where I dont know how to handle it...

On my ASP.NET site you can search for data if you click on a CheckBox and then "search"...
The "Search" searches just for data where the CheckBox (e.g. CheckBox "Customer") is checked. The query takes the value in the database and displays just data where "Customer" = 1.

For my adaption I´ve created a new Button which is on "ReadOnly" and is "Checked" if a certain condition is satisfied !BUT! the CheckBox is not available in the database... (name of the CheckBox is "Taker")

What I want to do now:

I want to search for all data where the CheckBox "Taker" is checked by the user - The user clicks on the CheckBox "Taker" and then clicks on "search".

**Is there any possibility to search for datas where the CheckBox "Taker" is set (checked) by the user which is not available in the database?**

Hopefully I could outline my problem as good as possible, so you understand it...

P.S.: English isn´t my main language ;)

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: You need to take a column named "Taker" in database and use data type bit.

Use check attribute of checkbox like this:
 
      checked='Eval("<%#Taker%>")'
where taker is a bit value in database

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. The problem is that the user can insert a new record and the "CheckBox" is only set on a logic on the surface. Is there a possibility to insert the value of the CheckBox "Taker" into the database?

Comment: Why not? 
bool check = checkbox1.checked;
If checkbox1 is checked then check will contain 1 else 0 and likewise you can save its value in database. What problem are you getting with this?